# Tensorflow: Repeat(tile) elements of a Tensor

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, tensor

I have an input tensor as follow:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

and the 'multiple' tensor:

```
mul= tf.constant([1, 3, 2])
```

Is it possible to tile a 3D tensor with the first element of `a` appears once, the second appears 3 times, the last element appears twice?

```
result = [
             [[1, 2, 3]],
             [[4, 5, 6],[4, 5, 6],[4, 5, 6]],
             [[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
                                   ]
```

Tensorflow 0.12

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Read about [tensors and shapes from the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/dims_types).

To understand why it is not possible imagine the matrix that has different number of elements in each row. It will clearly be not a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
mul = np.array([1,3,2])
result = []
for i in range(len(mul)):
  result.append(np.tile(a[i], (mul[i], 1)))
result = np.array(result)
```

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for your help. However, I don't think it is possible to use numpy inside Tensorflow's graph. I edited my question to clarify the inputs.

Comment: tensorflow also has tf.tile. very similay to numpy's tile.

Comment: Yep. However, I could not think of a way to output a tensor like what I want. I think it is impossible to get that output in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you cannot have non-rectangular tensors in tensorflow. That is what is causing the problem. Otherwise I just extended the code of @Kris to run wholly on tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
mul = tf.constant([1,3,2])
result = []
for i in range(3):
  result.append(tf.tile(a[i],[mul[i]]))
print([r.eval() for r in result])
#r_tensor = tf.stack(0,[r for r in result]) # Not possible
```